# on("click") not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi Friend in my code i used `on()` function to handling table rows which are created after body load I just wanted to delete these rows by clicking on `.delRow` but my code is notworking i cant figure out what is the exact problem is plz check my cod below  or you can check [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM5G3/)

**Used Jquery Version**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="emailTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2" >
                <strong>Share this greeting with your friend</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="417" align="right">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Friend's Email ID" class="mail" id="SendMail" name="SendMail">
            </td>
            <td width="156">  <div class="addRow">Add more Recipients</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {     
    $('.delRow').on( "click", function( event ) {
        $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    /*alert('hi');*/
    });
    $('.addRow').click(function(){
        $('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input type='text' placeholder=\"Enter Friend's Email ID\" class='mail' id='SendMail' name='SendMail'></td><td class='delRow'> <img src='images/Cross.png' alt=' ' ></td></tr>")
    })
});
```

Please help me guys

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the delRow elements are created dynamically

```
$('#emailTable').on("click", '.delRow',function (event) {
    $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    /*alert('hi');*/
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D639e/)

Answer (score 1):

`Delegate` the click event to the element's `static parent` or to the `document`.

Try,

```
$(document).on("click",'.delRow', function( event ) {
        $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```